# Who are the people referenced in "You Don't Belong" by Bad Religion?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, punk

The song ["You Don't Belong" by Bad Religion](https://www.badreligion.com/albums/13/The_Process_Of_Belief) obviously references the SoCal punk scene they were a part of. In it, a number of people are mentioned by name.

> missy was a teen blue video star,
> tom took his life in his mother's car,
> milo went to college but you knew about that,
> rodney played our records,
> jimmy started riots,
> laurie was always quiet, she was battling depression
>
> (...)
>
> jack wore a skirt but he knew how to scrap,
> billy went to county on a class one possession,
> wendy went to school while her daddy shot smack,
> eugene kept a list,
> mugger was security,
> mary she kept her purity, we were all in it together

**Who are they?**

Some are obvious, like [Milo who went to college](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milo_Goes_to_College) or [Rodney who played their records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodney_on_the_ROQ), but is it known who the others are?

Has the band ever talked about it in interviews?

---

I saw some speculation on [a discussion board](https://www.thebrpage.net/discography/song.asp?songName=You+Don%27t+Belong):

- Missy — ?
- Tom — Tom Clement, known from "I Give You Nothing"
- Milo — Milo Aukerman, from the Descendents
- Rodney — Rodney on the ROQ
- Jimmy — ? <sup>†</sup>
- Laurie — possibly Laurie Anderson
- Jack — Jack Grisham, from TSOL
- Billy — Brett Gurewitz himself
- Wendy — ?
- Eugene — ?
- Mugger — a roadie for Black Flag
- Mary — ?

<sup>†: The lyrics on their official homepage have him as Jimmy, but a number of other sources have him as GG, referring to either Greg Ginn or GG Allin.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Lead vocalist and songwriter Greg Graffin gives a description of where the title originated along with the different names and meanings mentioned in the song.

[Song Meaning](http://www.thebrpage.net/theanswer/?article=you_don%27t_belong):

> **Greg Graffin: "If you ever get a hold of our first EP, a 7", there's a guy with a jacket - a leather jacket - in the audience and it says,
>   'You don't belong' on it. That's where we got the title from. And it
>   was sort of the attitude all through the punk era; none of us felt
>   like we belonged. But we certainly felt like we should belong, because
>   we had something to say."**
>
> **Missy** -  "Blue movie" is another term for a porn movie. There's one famous porn star named Missy in particular.
>   She's in the encyclopedia as the only porn star with that name. She
>   lived in San Fernando Valley, where also the origin of Bad Religion
>   lies. It's possible that they knew each other from school as they were
>   all of the same age.
>
> **Tom** - Tom Clement One of Brett's friends who died in a car accident in 1986 (Brett thinks he committed suicide). The song Give
>   You Nothing has an alternate name called "Tom Clements".
>
> **Milo** - Milo Aukerman The singer of the Descendents. "Milo goes to college" is the title of one of the Descendents albums.
>
> **Rodney** - Rodney Bingenheimer A famed Hollywood radio DJ on the notable Los Angeles rock station KROQ. Famous from his "Rodney on the
>   roq" show on which he played Bad Religion for the first time on the
>   radio.
>
> **GG** - G.G. Allin or Greg Ginn Either G.G. Allin, an American punk rock singer-songwriter who performed and recorded with many groups
>   during his career, or Greg Ginn, the founder and guitarist of Black
>   Flag, is meant.
>
> **Laurie** - This could possibly be Laurie Anderson, the only one alternative/punk music in the business I can think of with the name
>   Laurie.
>
> **Jack** - Jack Grisham The singer of TSOL. He was known to wear a skirt on stage.
>
> **Billy** - Brett Gurewitz Billy is an alias for Brett himself (as in No Control / Into the Unknown's Billy Gnosis). This is a  reference to
>   when he was caught with ten balloons of heroin and was ordered by the
>   court to go to rehab.
>
> **Wendy** - Mr. Brett's daughter's name is Wendy
>
> **Eugene** - Eugene A skinhead who appeared in the 1981 punk rock documentary film "The Decline of Western Civilization".
>
> **Mugger** - Steve Corbin Mugger was his nickname. He was a roadie for Black Flag.
>
> **Mary** - Mary Harron, news reporter/publisher, possibly sarcasm with the line here.?